# How to use pine-script's plotcandle () function

Tags: pine-script

Tell me about the plotcandle () function.
If you do not specify the bordercolor option when using this function, the border display will default to black.
I want to turn off the frame display in advance.
How do I write the code?

Comment: Please visit help center, take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and How to Ask. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducile](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your attempt, input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Use `bordercolor = na`. If you are not using wicks, also use `wickcolor = na`, otherwise small dot artifacts tend to appear.

```
//@version=4
study("")
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, wickcolor = na, bordercolor = na)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but the result is different if you uncheck it and if you set na. Attach the image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9buZ.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifJSq.png

Comment: Added an example with what I get here.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bordercolor = na` results in the borders disappearing, leaving a gap between the candle and the wicks. If you go to the settings / style menu you can't change the border color from there, and if you uncheck the box to display the border, or the box to display the candle, the whole candle disappears.

**Alternative solutions:**

Using transparency has similar results to using `bordercolor = na`.

Set candle and border to the same color:
`color = color.green, bordercolor = color.green`
Works well with a single color.

However if you use an expression such as:
`color = close >= open ? color.green : color.red, bordercolor = close >= open ? color.green : color.red`
and you go to settings / style you will find that unchecking the tick boxes to display either the candle or border will result in the candle disappearing. At least you can still set the colors of the candle / border independently. You could set `editable = false` to hide the candle's style settings completely.